# Javascript Scroll Animation Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I attempted to make an animation, so that a header and a paragraph will increase in size when a user has scrolled to it. When the user scrolls past the header, the text will shrink back.

I had an issue getting this to work, but I got it after looking at: [Animate on scroll with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572574/animate-on-scroll-with-jquery)

However, the font increases jerkily when I scroll down. Oddly, it works better when I scroll up.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
function onScroll(event){
 $('#sched li').each(function () {
        var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop()+250;
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = currLink.find("div");
        if (refElement.offset().top <= scrollPos && (refElement.offset().top+refElement.height())>scrollPos){
            currLink.find("h1").stop().animate({fontSize:'40px'},300);
            currLink.find("p").stop().animate({fontSize:'30px'},300);
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
        if(currLink.hasClass("active")){
        currLink.find("h1").stop().animate({fontSize:'20px'},300);
        currLink.find("p").stop().animate({fontSize:'15px'},300);
        currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
        }
    });
}
});
```

I am somewhat new to this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to debounce your scroll events to get good performance. Here's a great article about the technique: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle/code snippet for me to experiment. I think I might be able to figure it out if you can provide your HTML and CSS.

Comment: Thank you for the article, I am looking over it. I also have the jsfiddle setup [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sLfb9dep/3/)

Comment: I tried debouncing, but it made my code slower. I might be implementing it wrong, but I followed the article.